# How do I get gold on track 2 in Trackmania Turbo VR?

Tags: trackmania-turbo

The ghost car starts falling over the first ledge, then suddenly starts falling faster. I have no idea what I can do to catch up with it.

https://www.twitch.tv/videos/254200325

Comment: hmm, interesting

Comment: The annoying thing is that this silver medal is holding me back from locked content.